# Fibonacci threads with restricted levels of recursion

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to implement threads to calculate Fibonacci series in the manner depicted below:

```
                       fib(n)
                          /\
                         /  \
                 fib(n-1)   fib(n-2)
                   /\            /\
                  /  \          /  \
          fib(n-2) fib(n-3) fib(n-3) fib(n-4)
```

After this level I am allowed to use fib function to calculate the remaining terms. I have written the code but I am getting confused at a couple of places. I have provided comment at places where I am getting confused. Any guidance in this regards is highly appreciated:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h> /* need to calculate which I will implement later */

void *fibr(void *n);
void *fibr_1(void *k);
signed long long int fibonacci(signed long long int);

  int main(){
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    pthread_t tid,tid1;
    int result,result1;
    signed long long int n=6;
    signed long long int m=7;

     result=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,fibr,&n);
        if(result){
               perror("pthread_create");
                return 1;
            }
     result1=pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,fibr,&m);
        if(result1){
            perror("pthread_create");
             return 1;
            }
        if(pthread_join(tid,NULL)){
            perror("pthread_join");
            return 1;
            }
        if(pthread_join(tid1,NULL)){
            perror("pthread_join");
            return 1;
            }
       printf("Fib value=%lld\n",n+m);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
 void *fibr(void *n){
   signed long long int *y=n;
   signed long long int x=*y;
   pthread_t tid2,tid3;
   signed long long int i,j;
   /* How do I assign values to i , j in order to 
     achieve the level viz fib(n-2)....fib(n-4) */
    if(pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,fibr_1,&i))
     {
        perror("pthread_create");
      }

     if(pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,fibr_1,&j))
      {
  perror("pthread_create");
      }
    if(pthread_join(tid2,NULL))
        {
          perror("pthread_join");
         }

    if(pthread_join(tid3,NULL))
        {
          perror("pthread_join");
         }
     /* How to return the values of i, j combined with *y . if I do *y+i+j, the result                        
      is not coming correctly */
     *y=fibonacci(x);
      return NULL;
       }

    void *fibr_1(void *k){
    long long int *a=k;
    long long int b=*a;
      *a=fibonacci(b);
       return NULL;
      }

      signed long long int fibonacci(signed long long int x){
          if((x==0)||(x==1))
           return x;
           return fibonacci(x-1)+fibonacci(x-2);
         }
```

Doubts: In line comments. ( Unable to figure out a way of passing values between main threads and the child threads. Please suggest)

Comment: +1 for the neatly drawn diagram.

Comment: Why? It makes no sense; using threads like this will not break down the problem into smaller parts that can be solved in parallel.

Comment: @R.. I'm guessing the choice of threads isn't a choice, but part of the assignment

Comment: Unless the point of the assignment is to realize that some computations don't parallelize, it makes no sense to me...

Comment: as Brc pointed out, its an assignment which has several parts. This is the second last one. I am trying now to pass parameters thru an array so that each routine will have a disctinct address space. Any other suggestion fellows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to make use of a simple structure which will hold both your values to operate on & the result and pass that as thread data. The code could look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>       /* need to calculate which I will implement later */

typedef signed long long int fibval; /*just to make everything less cluttered*/

void *fibr (void *n);
void *fibr_1 (void *k);
fibval fibonacci (fibval);

typedef struct _param_basket{
    fibval in_param; /* Will hold value to be operated in thread */
    fibval out_param; /* Will hold result of operation in thread */
}param_basket;

int main ()
{
/* Commented to remove warnings
  clock_t begin, end;
  double time_spent;
*/
  pthread_t tid, tid1;
  int result, result1;
  fibval n = 6;

  param_basket b1, b2;
  b1.in_param = n-1; /* This will contain fib(n-1) eventually*/
  b1.out_param = 0;

  b2.in_param = n-2;
  b2.out_param = 0; /* This will contain fib(n-2) eventually*/

  result = pthread_create (&tid, NULL, fibr, &b1);
  if (result)
    {
      perror ("pthread_create");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  result1 = pthread_create (&tid1, NULL, fibr, &b2);
  if (result1)
    {
      perror ("pthread_create");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  if (pthread_join (tid, NULL))
    {
      perror ("pthread_join");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  if (pthread_join (tid1, NULL))
    {
      perror ("pthread_join");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

 /* fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)*/
  printf ("Fib value (%lld) =%lld\n",n, b1.out_param + b2.out_param);

  pthread_exit (NULL);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void *
fibr (void *n) /* will receive n-1 & n-2 */
{
  param_basket * b = (param_basket *)n;

  pthread_t tid2, tid3;

  /* How do I assign values to i , j in order to
 achieve the level viz fib(n-2)....fib(n-4) */
  param_basket b3, b4;
  b3.in_param = b->in_param-1; /* n-2 when n-1 , n-3 when n-2 */
  b3.out_param = 0; /* This will contain fib(n-2) & fib(n-3) eventually in diff threads*/
  b4.in_param = b->in_param-2; /* n-3 when n, n-4 when n-2 */
  b4.out_param = 0; /* This will contain fib(n-3) & fib(n-4) eventually in diff threads*/

  if (pthread_create (&tid2, NULL, fibr_1, &b3))
    {
      perror ("pthread_create");
      return NULL;
    }

  if (pthread_create (&tid3, NULL, fibr_1, &b4))
    {
      perror ("pthread_create");
      return NULL;
    }
  if (pthread_join (tid2, NULL))
    {
      perror ("pthread_join");
      return NULL;
    }

  if (pthread_join (tid3, NULL))
    {
      perror ("pthread_join");
      return NULL;
    }
  /* How to return the values of i, j combined with *y . if I do *y+i+j, the result
     is not coming correctly */
  /* Just combine the outputs! */
  b->out_param = b3.out_param + b4.out_param;

  return NULL;
}

/* Second level thread ... no more wretched spawn! Direct calc*/
void *
fibr_1 (void *k)
{
  param_basket * b = (param_basket *)k;
  b->out_param = fibonacci(b->in_param);

  return NULL;
}

fibval
fibonacci (fibval x)
{
  if ((x == 0) || (x == 1))
    return x;
  return fibonacci (x - 1) + fibonacci (x - 2);
}
```

Hope this helps!